# How to return a requisition json of a function for data-formatter - Bootstrap Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, relationship, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to return a value from my `getJSON` in a function for data-formatter of the bootstrap-table, but I can't, it's appearing just a "-". Can you help me with that solution? I want to do a requisition some like a relationship, how you can to see below.

**HTML**

`<th data-formatter="Category" data-sortable="true">Category</th>`

**Javascript:**

```
function Category (value, row, index) {
var data = null;
$.getJSON(datasrc+"/"+row.category_id, function(d){
data = d.name;
});
return data;
}
```